# Error: Can't get some «class» of {«class», «class», ...}

Tags: applescript

I'm writing an Applescript for use in iTunes in which at some point I want to select any track from a list of tracks, but the way I expected it to work gives an error. Here's the code:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set thePlaylist to the first playlist whose name is "Missing track count"
    -- ...
    -- populate a list of strings: albumList
    -- ...
    repeat with albumName in the albumList
        set theAlbum to (the tracks of thePlaylist whose album is albumName)
        display dialog "Found " & (count theAlbum) & " tracks in the album"
        set aTrack to some track of theAlbum -- ERROR OCCURS HERE
    end repeat
end tell
```

The error I get when I execute the script from within iTunes is:

> Can't get some «class cTrk» of {«class cFlT» id 16112 of «class cUsP» id 15982 of «class cSrc» id 65 of application "iTunes", ... etc}

Now, I don't really see why it doesn't work, although I guess it must have something to do with the fact that the items in theAlbum are file tracks from a user playlist from the source from the iTunes application instead of 'just' tracks. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Where is `aTrack` coming from?

Comment: would have been nice if you had provided a working example.  see mine below.

Comment: Ok, sorry. Based on your reply, I stripped down the example to the essence of my confusion. This works: `tell application "iTunes" to set aTrack to some track`, but this doesn't work: `tell application "iTunes" to set aTrack to some track as track`. Why?

Comment: The problematic code in your comment can be made even simpler: `tell application "iTunes" to get some track as track`. The issue with this sample is not the same as in the question. To coerce one class to another, a [coercion handler](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_script_classes/SAppsScriptClasses.html) must be defined by the application. Apparently, iTunes doesn't define a coercion handler from tracks to tracks. This doesn't appear to be too uncommon: `window 1 as window`.

Answer (score 1):

In this example I use `some item` instead of `some track`, which works OK.

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set thePlaylist to the first playlist
    set x to (the tracks of thePlaylist)
    set aTrack to some item in x
end tell
```

results in

```
URL track id 87 of library playlist id 82 of source id 64 of application "iTunes"
```

Since all the items in your example inherit from track, I don't know why it doesn't work, but it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks, although it doesn't answer my question, it does help me out. (Maybe I asked the wrong question.)

Answer (score 0):

`theAlbum` is a list, not a playlist, so it doesn't have track elements; it only has [items](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/reference/ASLR_classes.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-250807).

The documentation on lists, where it states "You can also refer to indexed list items by class." is incomplete and thus misleading. It seems you can only do this with to built-in classes. From what I can glean, here's why:

[Object specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH218-SW7) ([2](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_object_specifiers/SAppsObjectSpecifiers.html)) are [based on key-value coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_object_specifiers/SAppsObjectSpecifiers.html). A [specifier might identify](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_get_set/SAppsGetSet.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002164-CH18-SW1) a property (an object attribute or a to-one relationship) or element (a to-many relationship). In the example, we're dealing with elements. To handle elements, the underlying Objective-C class must implement a [collection accessor pattern](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/AccessorConventions.html). That is, it must [implement at least `-<key>`, or `-countOf<Key>` and `-objectIn<Key>AtIndex:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_get_set/SAppsGetSet.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002164-CH18-SW1) (it can, of course, implement all of them). The list class does this for a set number of Applescript classes (if you peeked at the ObjC source for the list class, you'd find methods like `countOfApplication` and `-objectInNumberAtIndex:`). It could conceivably support arbitrary element object specifiers with an appropriate `-doesNotRecognizeSelector:` handler, but lists don't appear to have been implemented this way. Since lists don't have `-track`, `-countOfTrack` or `-objectInTrackAtIndex:` handlers, they can't deal with a specifier such as "`first track of trackList`".

Comment: That doesn't make sense, since the error specifically states that the list contains file tracks, and according to the page you referred to, 'you can also refer to indexed list items by class'.

Comment: Does the update make more sense? The relevant information is scattered throughout Apple's documentation on Applescript, but it's worth it to read through the docs and coalesce the information.

Comment: Also, if an Apple engineer with access to the AppleScript source happens to read this, could you confirm my suspicions (as long as it doesn't break any NDA)?